# Video upload checksums not matching

Tags: upload, checksum

We have a setup that takes a small quantity of small video uploads directly from people's mobile phones using apps, onto a small VPS. It rejects them if the MD5 checksum on the phone doesn't match the checksum on the server. We're finding that roughly 50% of the uploads are failing first time because of this.

It strikes me that the fail rate is far above what one would expect. What is likely to be causing this problem?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What apps are used to upload the video? How does the upload process work, and how are the files stored? Etc.

Comment: What have you done so far to track the source of problem?

Comment: Proprietary apps are used. Their development was outsourced, so I don't know much about that. The files are stored in a temporary folder when they are uploaded, and there the checksum is checked straight away before anything else is done with them. I don't really know where to start looking for problems, other than the Apache error log, which is empty.